# Python - Selenium - Generating Mouse Click

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I am trying selenium webdriver. I am testing youtube kind of website, where I want to click on play button of video player. Video is embeded into flash, so How can access play, pause button.

Is there any other library available to generate click at specific mouse co-oridates & as well as allow me to record test case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found pymouse library, which preety straight forward.